# symfony2 verbose formatter, adding the line number and the file name to the logged message

Tags: symfony, logging

I need to add extra data into my logger, I'd like to add the file name and the line where the logger was called from. Do I have to create a custom class for that or are the file name and the line already sent somewhere within the predefined loggers?

Comment: I found this http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/reference/dic_tags.html#monolog-processor. But after adding a new processor globally, my log files are not created anymore:
`talkative_processor:
        class: Monolog\Processor\IntrospectionProcessor
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.processor }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works now!!
Both custom processor and custom formatter have to be added.